# Questions about the intuition on or physical meaning of probability space, random number, and stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, randomness

I have a question about the physical meaning of, or the mathematical intuition on, the mathematical concept of probability space, random number, and stochastic process. Mainly, I would like to ask about the exact counterpart of the events, random numbers, and stochastic processes in particular examples.

The book I first encountered those concepts (the theory of open quantum systems by H.-P. Breuer et al.) states that a random number is a map $X: \Omega\times T\rightarrow R$ with respect to the probability space $(\Omega, A, \mu)$, and the probability distribution is defined by $P(x)=\mu(X(t)^{-1}(x))$.

I am having trouble matching this definition with the physical stochastic process. The problem is because, according to the above definition, the probability of events($\mu(B), B\in\Omega$) does not vary in time, but instead, the map from the probability space to $R$ varies in time. I first thought that microstates with equal a priori probability should be events, but I am having difficulty figuring out what " events " should be in some examples. For instance, if I think of a taxi driver randomly picking up a passenger, then obviously, the number of passengers should be a random number, but I don't know what should be corresponding events. Could someone please help me understand the concept?

Edit))
Symbol Definitions

$\Omega$ : sample space

$A$ : $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$

$\mu$ : Probability measure

Comment: I hope this does not get moved to the Math site. I think there could be some interesting answers for physicists. In the meantime,  could you define your symbols?

Comment: @mmesser314 Oh, sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question.

Comment: (a) What is $T$? (b) The way you wrote the equation for the probability distribution $P$, $P(x)$ does not depend on time $t$. Is this intentional? I would actually guess that the intent of the notation is that the probability distribution is not meant to depend on time, but that you need a collection of random draws (indexed by $t$) in order to be able to infer the distribution. (This is just a guess though, I'm not clear on all the notation).

Comment: @Andrew (a) T is just a set of parameters that usually serves as time. (b) It's my mistake. It should be P(x, t). I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect knowledge of the state of a system at one time determines what it will do later. In your thermodynamic example, you can take $\Omega$ to be the set of possible states of the system at a chosen fixed time, and $\mu$ determines the probability distribution of those states at that time. These data do not change with time, but they still determine the values and probability distributions of observations, which do vary with time.

In the case of the taxi driver, you have do something similar: an outcome in $\Omega$ represents the state of the entire world at a chosen time $t_0$, including the driver, passengers, and any factors that might later affect when passengers get on or off the taxi. $X(x,t)$ then predicts the number of passengers in the taxi at time $t$ by running the state at $t_0$ forward (or backwards) in time. The intuition in both the thermodynamic and macroscopic cases is that $\mu$ represents *ignorance* of a "real, complete" condition of the world, which deterministically produces all later (and previous!) observations. This is in contrast to a picture where the initial condition might be known but the evolution can be nondeterministic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have one question about the random process $X(t)$. I am currently understanding $X(t)$ as a physical process that maps an event to a particular element of the Borel set. But if I identify the element of event space $\Omega$ as one of all possible states, then I wonder how I can think of a random process that varies in time.

Comment: For in most cases the outcome, which is an element of the Borel set, is the concomitant of a particular state and the physical process that maps that process to the physical observable, which should not change in time. Also, if the event space consists entirely of the possible states at a specific time, then the domain of the random variable seems to change in time. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I also have an additional question. In physics, the stochastic process generally originates from the stochastical fluctuation of the physical system, which is an element of $\Omega$. However, the time dependence of such fluctuation is entirely tossed to the stochastical process $X(x,t)$. So I wonder if it is still valid to identify $\Omega$ as a set of entire physical states in such a case since then the time dependence is on $\Omega$ not $X(x,t)$, which does not match with the mathematical definition.

Comment: @JonginnYun I am confused by everything you just said. $\Omega$ is not the set of events; it is the set of outcomes. The Borel algebra on $\Omega$ consists of the events, which are sets of outcomes. $X(t)$ maps from outcomes to reals and does not interact with the Borel sets (events). You measure the probability of $X=x$ by taking $X(t)^{-1}(x)$ and measuring it with $\mu.$ I.e. you consider all states of the world producing $X=x$ at time $t,$ simulate them backwards to the fixed time of the states in $\Omega,$ then measure ($\mu$) the resulting set of outcomes.

Comment: @JonginnYun The time you choose for the states you place in $\Omega$ is *fixed*. The domain of $X(t)$ is always the same $\Omega,$ it always takes states from that *fixed* time and produces the value of $X$ at some other time $t.$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant elementary event by events. Anyhow, I'll elaborate on the question with the example of the hyperfine field generated by a particular nuclear spin system with fluctuating nuclear spins. If I measure the hyperfine field generated within a time interval $[t_1, t_2]$, the outcome will fluctuate since the nuclear spin system fluctuates.

Comment: In this example, it seems every possible nuclear spin system will constitute $\Omega$, and the hyperfine field I measure shall seemingly lie in the Borel space. The problem is that the map between a particular nuclear spin state to the hyperfine field is not a function of time, and I do not know where to give the time dependence.

Comment: @JonginnYun $X(t)$ is a map from the spins at some fixed time $t_0$ to the fields at a different time $t.$ If the spins are changing with time then the map $X(t)$ changes with $t,$ because you should envision it as a time-independent part $F$ that computes fields from spins composed with a time-dependent part $U(t)$ that computes "spins at $t$" from "spins at $t_0$." (If the spins are not changing on their own but only because you are measuring them I don't think this formalism works.) (Also, I have no idea about the specifics of the system you're talking about.)

Comment: The last comment clearly resolves the confusion I had. Thanks a lot!